# Lucene - How to find numbers in String field

Tags: lucene

I have a String field in Lucene (4.7) and I want to find in this field number that is different from a number I have.
How can I do it?

For example, the field include "abc345 + kl908" and I want to find "abc" followed by any number that is different from 123. Especially I don't want it to find "abcde" because "de" is not a number.

Is there a query that can find it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What about using a [RegexQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/sandbox/org/apache/lucene/sandbox/queries/regex/RegexQuery.html?)?

In this way you can specify a regular expression that it's able to validate the field following your constraints.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there is something like this.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, you should think to mark the discussion as answered.